# Efficient way to split a byte array to map the fields in a java class object

Tags: java, arrays, readfile

Is there a more efficient way to break the data in a byte array in Java?
I have written the following function to read a binary file with fixed length data field. But the performance are really slow, I need to read a binary file with 30,000 records each with the length of 300 bytes, and each record contain 240 fields.
Any advise?

```
public void breakField(byte[] input) {

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);

    byte[] tmp = new byte[2];
    bais.read(tmp);
    this.id = new String(tmp);

    tmp = new byte[4];
    bais.read(tmp);
    this.name = new String(tmp);

    tmp = new byte[8];
    bais.read(tmp);
    this.phone = new String(tmp);

    tmp = new byte[15];
    bais.read(tmp);
    this.otherInfo = new String(tmp);

    .... more fields...

}
```

Comment: Try to read file record-by-record (every 300 bytes) rather than field-by-field and split the read data into data fields later in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the entire file into a `byte[]` array, if the file is larger than the amount of space available in memory to the JVM, then you will get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Instead, you can use a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) in conjunction with a [`FileReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).  This will allow you to read the file piece by piece without loading the entire thing into memory.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/my/file"));
```

To load the data record-by-record, simply read in 300 bytes at a time when you call [`BufferedReader.read`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).  If you prefer to deal with individual fields, instead of reading 300 bytes at a time, just read the number of bytes that corresponds to the length of the next field.